# Can i use pointers in and with template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do someting like this:

```cpp
template<typename FromType, typename ToType>
class TEncodingCache
{
public:
    ToType* Get(const FromType* Source)
    {
        return Data[Source];
    }

private:
    std::map<FromType*, ToType*> Data;
};
```

In main function:

```cpp
TEncodingCache<char, char16_t> cache;
cache.Get("test");
```

I obtain this error:
`binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const FromType *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: Your `Get` parameter is a `const FromType *`, but your map's key is a `FromType *`. Are you aware that in C++ you cannot convert a pointer to a constant object to a pointer to a non-constant object, and that you can only compare pointers to the same type, and, furthermore, pointer comparison is not portable, except in certain narrow situations? There are multiple reasons why the shown code will not work, and comprises undefined behavior. C++ simply does not work this way.

Comment: Notice that there are no guaranties in C++ to have `"test" == "test"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use pointers in and with template parameters?

Yes.

> I obtain this error: binary '[': no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'const FromType *' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)

That error occurs because your `std::map` expects keys of type `FromType*`, and you are trying to pass it the `Source` argument of type `const FromType *`.  The compiler won't allow that because it would violate the const-correctness guarantee (i.e. when you declared `Source` to be of type `const FromType *` you effectively promised that the function wouldn't modify the object the pointer points to, and passing `Source` to `std::map::operator[]` as a `FromType *` would allow `std::map::operator[]` to modify it, if it wanted to).

The easy fix would be to change your member-variable to this:

```
std::map<const FromType*, ToType*> Data;
```